# Count with multiple criteria

Tags: excel

Let 'sheet1', column A be number of category of the department (hr = 0, law department = 1 etc)

Let 'sheet1', column B be text of whether the task has been completed by that department (if there is a text, it is completed, if there is a blank, it's still active)

Now, I want to summarize those department by effectivness. So, I want the count of the answers made by each department.

If there were 10 tasks to the HR, 3 of whom are "blank", meaning 7 was answered, I want in another sheet that kind of statistics, like following

No., Department, Answered, Unanswered, Adressed

0   --------     HR    -----------     3    --------------      7     -----------     10

Those addresed i did easily with Countif function (=COUNTIF('Sheet'!A:A,"=0"), it shows me how many tasks was addressed.

Meanwhile i tried match, countif, countifs, if, vlookup among other stuff, it just calculates me in general, not by department

I hope you understand what I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data seems to contradict your narrative.

> <sub>If there were 10 tasks to the HR, 3 of whom are "blank", meaning 7 was answered,</sub>

Seems like the data should be more like,

```
No.     Department    Answered         Unanswered     Addressed
0 -------- HR ----------- 7 -------------- 3 ----------- 10
```

Answered (non-blank) should be,

```
=countifs('sheet1'!a:a, 0, 'sheet1'!b:b, "<>")
```

Unanswered (blanks) should be,

```
=countifs('sheet1'!a:a, 0, 'sheet1'!b:b, "=")
```